# How to replace Azure DNS A record with CNAME record using ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, cname, azure-rm-template, azure-dns

I am trying to replace an existing DNS A record with CNAME record having same name using ARM template. I have A record in DNS zone that looks like the following

- name - mylink
- value - 10.22.31.3
- Type - A
- TTL - 60

I want to have CNAME record in the same DNS zone that should look like following

- name - mylink
- value - cos.myaddress.test.net
- Type - CNAME
- TTL - 60

Currently my ARM template looks like following that creates A record

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/dnszones/A",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "name": "mylink",
      "properties": {
        "TTL": 60,
        "ARecords": [
          {
            "ipv4Address": "10.22.31.3"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

I tried to add another CNAME record to this are template which gave error on deployment.

> "code": "Conflict",

> "message": "The CNAME record could not be created because another record with the same name already exists in this zone."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error displayed, we can not create a `CNAME` record name that is the same as existing records sets in the same zone because *CNAME record sets cannot coexist with other record sets with the same name*. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#cname-records).

So we need to delete the old `A` records or create `CNAME` records with a different record name in this case.

When deploying your resources with the ARM template, you specify that the deployment is either an **incremental** update or a **complete** update. By default, the deployment is using incremental mode. You may consider using [complete mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes) to delete resources that exist in the resource group but aren't specified in the template.

However, the child resources type like `dnszones / *` does not support complete mode deletion.
[image]

In conclusion, we can not directly replace Azure DNS A record with the CNAME record using the ARM template. We need to delete the A records first with the Azure portal or other cmdlets then create CNAME records with the ARM template as usual.